# Qual a origem da expressão " Mês de São João é mijão"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, ditados, ditado-popular

Qual a origem da expressão " Mês de São João é mijão"?  Relacionado com a chuva?!

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa expressão, e não a encontro na net., Não nos queres dizer donde é que a conheces? Do contexto em que a ouviste não tens ideia do que significa?

Comment: são joao é o mês de Junho.

Comment: Apesar de perto de verão, significa que ainda chove. Portugal

Comment: Será da idade média?